# How to prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{99}}{e^x}=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> How to prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{99}}{e^x}=0$?

I wasn't sure how to do this because both the top and the bottom limits independently turns out to be infinity!

Comment: do you know l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: oh also, it's not.

Comment: @AndrewLi because 0 is suppose to be the right answer. Exponentials grow much faster than polynomials.

Comment: my apoligies it seems to be that i mis wrote infinity as 0 ill fix that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After successively applying L'Hopital's rule $100$ times, you get:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} {x^{99} \over e^x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} {99! \over e^x} = 0$$

This is due to the fact that exponentials always grow faster than polynomials. $e^x$ will eventually overcome $x^{99}$.

Answer (score 12):

For $x>0$ we have $e^x > \frac{x^{100}}{100!}$, hence $0 < {x^{99} \over e^x}< \frac{100 !}{x}$. This gives ${x^{99} \over e^x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.